# Get by Reflection Properties from a Class

Tags: c#

Lets assume that we have the following TestClass

```
public interface IBase
{
    int MyIntegerAA { get; set; }
}

public interface F : G
{
    string MyStringBB { get; set; }
}

public interface E : F
{
    string MyStringCC { get; set; }
    IBase xyz { get; set; }
}

public interface D : E
{
    int myint1 { get; }
    int myint2 { get; }
    int myint3 { get; }
    int myint4 { get; }
}

public interface C : D
{
    string MyString1{ get; set; }
}

public class B : C
{
    public int myint1 { get; }
    public int myint2 { get; }
    public int myint3 { get; }
    public int myint4 { get; }
    public string MyString1 { get; set; }
    public IBase xyz { get; set; }
}

public class A : B
{
    public string test1 { get; set; }
}
```

The question is, how we can "enumerate" each class and interface, to get back only its declared properties, without the reference on the Interface IBase during the enumeration.

For Example
If i try to get the Properties of Class B, then i get back the following

Current Father Is : GetProperties.Form1+TestClass+B
The number of public properties : 6

Property name: xyz
Property type: [GetProperties.Form1+TestClass+IBase]

Property name: myint1
Property type: [System.Int32]

Property name: myint2
Property type: [System.Int32]

Property name: myint3
Property type: [System.Int32]

Property name: myint4
Property type: [System.Int32]

Property name: MyString1
Property type: [System.String]

Is there any way, NOT to include the
Property name: xyz
Property type: [GetProperties.Form1+TestClass+IBase]

??

Comment: It is declared in `B` class so there's no other way than just ignoring it when iterating through all properties. You can remove derived properties from search by specifying `System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`.